# loading data using load_data in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7 and trying to load the data using `load_data`

```
import helper
import problem_unittests as tests

source_path = 'data/small_vocab_en'
target_path = 'data/small_vocab_fr'
source_text = helper.load_data(source_path)
target_text = helper.load_data(target_path)
```

Which gives me

```
<ipython-input-1-ec5ca37388cc> in <module>()
      7 source_path = 'data/small_vocab_en'
      8 target_path = 'data/small_vocab_fr'
----> 9 source_text = helper.load_data(source_path)
     10 target_text = helper.load_data(target_path)

/home/ubuntu/Documents/karim/Data/bse/phase3/deep_learning/Seq2Seq-Language-Translation/helper.pyc in load_data(path)
     13     """
     14     input_file = os.path.join(path)
---> 15     with open(input_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
     16         data = f.read()
     17 

TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

Comment: It seems that the `helper` module is incompatible with python2, because `encoding` is a parameter accepted only in Python3.  Try running your code with python3.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have to use python 2.7 only due to some other version issue. Could you please guide me to convert above part in python 2.7 compatibly. I tried with replacing `open('filename','r').read()` but still I was getting similar issue.

Comment: What's the issue you get when you remove encoding?

Comment: You can import an open function that supports encoding: from io import open